# Adding shadow to SVG on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, hover

I've been trying to add a shadow to an svg path when it is hovered. Here is a fiddle showing my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/do6fk291/

I've tried adding `filter: url(#blur-filter)` on hover which sort of works, but doesn't look completely right. I want the effect to appear as though the segment is lifting up off the page with a shadow behind it.

I've also looked at adding a stroke to it to add the darker color for the blur affect, but again the edges that touch the path don't look right.

Is there a way to blur just a stroke? Or another way of adding a shadow to this on hover?